# how to edit google meta verfication code in joomla 1.5 websites index page 

Tags: seo, joomla1.5

where is the option in joomla 1.5 to edit google meta tag verification code in my website.pls

Answer (score 0):

You need a plugin for that, this is not a feature built in to the Joomla core.

http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=google+verification&sa.x=0&sa.y=0